# Se build country for any Android emulator

Tags: android, build, resources, location, country

I'm developing an application which has a filter that separates the users by its device Build country. I'm using:

```
String locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

to get the country. Is there any way to check build country on AVD so that I can make sure that the code above is working?

Answer (score 1):

Open menu=>Setting=>Language& Keyboard=>Select Locale=>set any locale from this

Using cmd :

```
$ adb shell'
setprop persist.sys.language en;
setprop persist.sys.country IN;
stop;
sleep 5;
start'
```

If you want it programaically :

```
  Locale locale = null;
Configuration config=null;
 config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
locale = new Locale("en");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
config.locale = locale;
```